# Script for replacing variables in URL with VALUES from SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, url

We have a table with longitute and latitude data and we need a script to place this data correctly into an URL. This is our table:

```
CREATE TABLE "AIRON"."GPS_POSITION" 
(
 "GPS_POSITION_SEQ" NUMBER,  
 "LATITUDE"         NUMBER(10,6), 
 "LONGITUDE"        NUMBER(10,6)
  CONSTRAINT "PK_GPS_POSITION" PRIMARY KEY ("GPS_POSITION_SEQ")
);
```

This is the URL https://opentopomap.org/#map=17/LONGITUDE/LATITUDE in which we want to replace `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` with their spesific value from the table. Every `GPS_POSITION_SEQ` has a unique value for `LAT` and `LONG`.

Comment: What is the connection between the URL you showed us and the actual Oracle table?  (note: there needs to be a connection in order to answer your question)

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen , thank you for your comment. There is no direct connection between these two. We are working on an Oracle APEX application, which is linked to the table in this database. There is a button in our application that redirects you to http://opentopomap.org/ but the longitude and latitude values are missing. Thats why we need a script in between this button and the redirection to the website, that uses the PK to identify the right LONG and LAT

Answer (score 1):

Url is fixed?

You can try simple replace:

```
Select t.*,      REPLACE(Replace('https://opentopomap.org/#map=17/LONGITUDE/LATITUDE', 
       'LONGITUDE', 
        T.LONGITUDE),
'LATITUDE',
T.LATITUDE) AS MODIFIED_URL
From gps_position;
```

Cheers!!